# Deep Linking is returning the parameters associated with link even after the killing of application

Tags: android

Deep Linking is returning the parameters associated with link even after the killing of application.
I want to make sure when application is killed the parameters associated with deep link are null.

Comment: You are refering to [the android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) and deep links via intent data? Say so, provide example code. And no, you cannot erase data from an intent that you already passed on.

Comment: so in that case even if i kill my app,and launch the app gain,because of deep linking will it take me to the last visited page and not relaunch the app?

Comment: It is entirely up to your application how to handle incoming intents. If I get you correctly, you want deep links to work only when your app is already active, but not when the app is first started?